# Windows shortcut using JShortCut no console window

Tags: java, jshortcut

I've been experimenting with [JShortCut](https://github.com/jimmc/jshortcut) to create Windows shortcuts.

It works well, but I can't figure out how to disable the console window for the shortcut, because a console window will open up when you open the created shortcut. Ho can I disable the console window for the shortcut?

Comment: Show us the generated shortcut. In general you probably should be using `javaw.exe` to run your application instead of `java.exe`

Comment: Yes. That did the trick. Didn't think of that myself...